# TimescaleDB Questions

Tags: timescaledb

I'm making tests on TimescaleDB and it fits perfectly my needs (performance and functionalities) but I have some questions for the set-up and long time running operations.

I have followed the documentation to create an hypertable to store the raw data, and created several materialized views (with different time_bucket) and enabled continuous aggregate on it.

I have several questions to fully understand how to use it in the most efficient way.

- Best pratices indicates the chunk time of the hypertable should be dependent of the data inserted, and the server's RAM. Materialized view with continuous aggregate seems to be hypertable as well, should I reconfigure the chunk interval as well for it (the data inserted will be much lower than the original hypertabe) ?
- I would like to change the query used in the materialized view (changing an aggregate or adding a new column). How could I do that without loosing the actual data (because I only have 7 days of retention in the first hypertable) ?
- If materialized view are really hypertable on behind, can I set-up the name prefix, schema, ... as I can for classic hypertables ?
- From the documentation, it is not really clear on if it makes sense to create primary keys on hypertable. Should/Can I also add indexes on the Materialized View to speed-up queries ?

This kind of questions is blocking me from really deploying it (and mostly the update of the materialized view), any help (or missed documentation) is welcomed :-)

Thanks,